# XSLT Escape Character not working

Tags: xslt, ansi-escape

I am trying to use escape charaters in my text output, as i would like too surround the output in emailData tags. I am using

```
<xsl:text>&#60;emailData&#62;</xsl:text>
```

In the XSLT to esnure that this works however because i am using a tool called Cast Iron for some reason it is not converting the `&#60;` into `<` and just spits out `&lt;emailData>`

You can see am image of it [HERE](http://i41.tinypic.com/295c0op.png) that illustrates the output i am getting. My source code is this. How else could i wrap this in emailData tags?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:text>&#60;emailData&#62;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>From: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="from/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>To: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="to/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Subject: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="subject/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Content-Type: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="contentType/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>  boundary="</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="boundary/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>MIME-Version: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="mimeVersion/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="email">
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>--</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../header/boundary/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Content-Type: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="contentTypeBody/text()"/>
        <xsl:text> charset="us-ascii"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Content-Transfer-Encoding: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="contentTransfer/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="body/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Attachment">
        <xsl:for-each select="Attachments">
            <xsl:text>&#0010;&#0010;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../header/boundary/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Content-Type: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="attachmentContentType/text()"/>
            <xsl:text> name="</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="attachmentDescription/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Content-Description: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="attachmentDescription/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="atachementDisposition/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Content-Transfer-Encoding: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="attachmentContentTransfer/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="attachementBody/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#60;/emailData&#62;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate XML directly rather than XML-encode text so

change

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:text>&#60;emailData&#62;</xsl:text>
```

to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

   <xsl:template match="/"><emailData><xsl:apply-templates/></emailData></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="header">
       <!-- <xsl:text>&#60;emailData&#62;</xsl:text>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

add disable-output-escaping="yes" to your `<xsl:text>`  elements:

`<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#60;...&#62;</xsl:text>`

will show up as

<...>

Comment: Nope when i add that the same output is created `&lt;emailData>`

Comment: disable-output-encoding will have no effect here as the stylesheet already says `<xsl:output method="text"/>` and d-o-e has no effect on text mode. The result tree generated by XSLt is presumably _not_ being serialised by xslt and is being passed to some other application which is then serialising it as XML. @liveek can you not just generate XML from your xslt ie generate a real <emailData> element? XSLT is rather optimised for generating XML element srather than XML encoded strings.